# Msi generated via Wix, Reporting ngen progress

Tags: wix, ngen

I'm running ngen which I've included in my Wvx files that generates the msi. however, running the installer in logging mode does not feed back if ngen had executed. Is there any way to confirm that an msi installed has ngened stuff?

Comment: Are you really shipping a version of ngen.exe? All you need to do is [Mark the managed files for NGen](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/ngen_managed_assemblies.html). (I've never looked at what logging or progress reporting that produces at install time, though.)

Comment: Nope definitely not shipping ngen.exe. I had already marked it for ngen, but the problem is I can't see it as actually done. In my testing I'm trying to check using ngen.exe display but came up with negative, so I want to look at the logs what happened.

Comment: `ngen display` doesn't give many details but it might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ngen.log file located in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 (On 64 bit windows .Net 4.5) and see if there are entries in it with timestamps similar to when you ran the msi.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708846%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)